# Como crear un arreglo bidimensional de n×n?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, lista, array-bidimensional

Estoy intentando crear un arreglo bidimensional de 10×10 con esta linea

```
let grid = Array(10).fill(Array(10).fill(false));
```

(Cabe destacar que es un arreglo de valores booleanos) Pero las listas internas son todas referencias de sí mismas.

¿Hay alguna forma de crear un arrglo bidimensional de una forma similar pero que todas sean listas diferentes?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), que toma como primer parámetro un Array y como segundo una función opcional para cada uno de esos elementos

> Array.from(arrayLike[, mapFn[, thisArg]])

Por ejemplo:

```js
let grid = Array.from(Array(10), () => new Array(10).fill(false))

// Para hacer la prueba de que cada array es un nuevo
// Modificamos algún dato y comprobamos si solo modifica esa valor
console.log("Valor inicial", grid)
grid[0][0] = true
console.log("Despues de modificar", grid)
```

Como ves, después de modificar, solo hemos modificado el valor en una posición concreta del array, lo que significa que cada uno tiene una referencia diferente.